# How can this app interact with Bluetooth commands?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android world, and I'm examining this app: https://github.com/evanemran/android_app_muzix

If I try on my car, I see that it interacts with bluetooth commands (next/prev/volume up/down, and so on).

How can this be possible if it doesn't contain any reference to BluetoothManager, BluetoothAdapter, BroadcastReceiver, AudioManager, or Intent filters related to Bluetooth events?

I don't believe that's "magic": so what's the connection here between the two context?

Comment: see gradle he is using library , from library i think that possible

Comment: An app doesn't have to use bluetooth to react to events like next/prev song and start/stop. The Android OS handles it and just forwards the events to whatever music app is currently active.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann but if I press "next", there should be part of the code that tell mediaPlayer to play next song, right? I don't see any of this in that code.

Comment: You should better look at the complete APK using Jadx-Gui. Check the AndroidManifest.xml for Bluetooth related permissions and then make a full text search on the decompiled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app you linked uses the Android framework's [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer).

The Android OS handles all the Bluetooth related stuff, when a connected device triggers media keys. It then forwards the media key events to the currently active media player.

`MediaPlayer` handles the action that are triggered by the play / pause, next / back button presses itself.

So the app that you linked doesn't really do that much itself. It is mostly a GUI for the built in `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: I see, but I also see it react to Bluetooth commands I press on my car (on the wheel for example).

Comment: That's what I meant. The Android OS handles that. Just the same way it handles keyboard inputs from a Bluetooth keyboard. Apps don't have to implement anything Bluetooth related to react to media keys.

Comment: I understand, but how can OS tell MediaPlayer to use "some function" when I Press next? There should be a connection :O

Comment: Example: how if I want to playPrev() function while pressing right button on my wheel? Or trigger a "blip" on left button on my wheel and keep playing playPrev()?